# Modular law for direct summands

Tags: modules, direct-sum

We know that if M is an R-module, A,B,C are submodules of M and C is subset of A then $ A \cap (B+C) = (A \cap B) +C $
What if we use $ \oplus $ instead of +. Is it true to write that equation again? Or should we add more things to make it true for direct sum?
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, consider $M=\mathbb{Z}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Take
\begin{align}
A=6\mathbb{Z},&& B=3\mathbb{Z},&&C=12\mathbb{Z}.
\end{align}
Then $C\subseteq A$, but $A\cap B=6\mathbb{Z}$ is not a direct summand of $C=12\mathbb{Z}$.